# How to create 3D water depth with ArcScene?

Tags: dem, 3d-analyst, arcscene, depth

I was trying to visualize flood depth in 3D using ArcScene. What I had for this purposes are:

1. high-resolution DTM of the valley
2. orthophoto and
3. Raster with flood depth information.

I have draped the orthophoto over the DTM and it looks like as follows:

[image]

Then I draped orthophoto over it:

[image]

Finally I overlayed flood map on top of orthophoto:
[image]

My question is , is there any way to visualize flood water in 3D with height. it looks like Flood depth raster only touches the base of the DTM. But I need to incorporate DTM + raster height in Flood depth map . How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

I would use this approach:

1. Add *flood deep* to *DTM* to create a new surface raster (use [Plus (3D Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.2/#/na/00q900000006000000/) tool).
   [image]
2. Drape the flood raster to the new surface.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the DTM as the [base height](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_a_raster_layer_s_base_heights_using_a_surface_in_ArcScene/00q80000005q000000/) for your flood depth raster and calculate a new height by adding the flood depths raster value to the dtm base height as a [vertical offset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Vertical_offsets_for_feature_layers_in_ArcScene/00q800000010000000/).

bearing in mind that water is flat (waves aside), you could also use a flat plane and calculate the flood limits as a height above sea level and set the height of the plane equal to that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regarding your first suggestion, the 'Expression' option (layer properties -> base height)is dead for a raster file in my ArcScene 10.1. This is only active when I use vector file. Would you please elaborate your second thoughts ?